# How to change the menuIsOpen props in custom component in react select?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

My select have following code:

```
<Select
          className="sui-w-64"
          options={options}
          aria-label="input-abc"
          name="input-abc"
          components={{ MenuList }}
          isMulti
          menuIsOpen={open}
          onMenuOpen={() => setOpen(true)}
          onMenuClose={() => setOpen(false)}
          closeMenuOnSelect={false}
          hideSelectedOptions={false}
        />
```

When I click on the button, I want to show the input field but because of the onMenuClose, I can not able to show the input field on button click inside MenuList components. Here is the code for this:

```
 const handleAddNew = async (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    console.log('boolean value in clicking on the add new button', props.selectProps.menuIsOpen);
    console.log('onMenuClose value in clicking on the add new button', props.selectProps.onMenuClose);
    // props.selectProps.menuIsOpen = true;
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault()
    setShowInputField(true);
  };
```

HELP WILL BE APPRECIATED. AS I DID NOT FIND A WAY TO FIX THIS.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAzF8.png)

I am trying to make the MenuIsOpen as true when i click on the add new button in the custom component but right now, the menuIsopen is false and because of which i can not display the desired behaviour when click action happen in the dropdown of react select.

Comment: can you add your code into codesandbox

Comment: @Thusithz, let me know if you know how to update it.

Comment: @Samndra Got busy. sorry for the late reply. I have posted my solution

Answer (score 0):

Since input field has **autofocus** that triggers `onMenuClose` i just modified that and restructure little bit but you can ignore restructure those and keep new **autoFouse** logic and try your functionality. Here is my code changes

https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-sun-t1se7u?file=/src/App.js

Let me know if that's not working. Cheers !!!